# Unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)' in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script that contains this command:

```
  SNAPSHOT_ID=$(bash <<-EOF 
              aws rds create-db-snapshot 
              --db-instance-identifier $RDS_INSTANCE_ID 
              --db-snapshot-identifier $RDS_INSTANCE_ID-manual-$NOW_DATE 
              --query 'DBSnapshot.[DBSnapshotIdentifier]' --output text 
EOF
   )
```

But I'm receiving this error:

> line 191: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you check your file for [carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a here-doc to send your command to a new shell (and you're already in a subshell):

```
snapshot_id=$(aws rds create-db-snapshot \
    --db-instance-identifier "$RDS_INSTANCE_ID" \
    --db-snapshot-identifier "$RDS_INSTANCE_ID-manual-$NOW_DATE" \
    --query 'DBSnapshot.[DBSnapshotIdentifier]' --output text)
```

You *do* have to escape your newlines, though.

I've also added quotes around parameter expansions and lowercased the one variable being created, as uppercase variable names are reserved for shell and utilities (see [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), fourth paragraph).

Comment: The command is inside a shell script. Is it possible to use your solution ?

Comment: @user1297406 Yes. This is the standard way to assign the output of shell command in a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your case but if the second `EOF` does not start from the beginning the line (column 1) you will get such an error. For example:

```
[root@tsekmanrhel771 ~]# cat eoftest.sh
#!/bin/sh

 SNAPSHOT_ID=$(bash <<-EOF
              aws rds create-db-snapshot 
              --db-instance-identifier $RDS_INSTANCE_ID 
              --db-snapshot-identifier $RDS_INSTANCE_ID-manual-$NOW_DATE 
              --query 'DBSnapshot.[DBSnapshotIdentifier]' --output text 
 EOF
   )
[root@tsekmanrhel771 ~]# ./eoftest.sh
./eoftest.sh: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
./eoftest.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SNAPSHOT_ID=$(bash <<EOF
aws rds create-db-snapshot --db-instance-identifier $RDS_INSTANCE_ID --db-snapshot-identifier $RDS_INSTANCE_ID-manual-$NOW_DATE --query 'DBSnapshot.[DBSnapshotIdentifier]' --output text
EOF
)
```

problems were with the "-" before EOF and the last ")" seemed to be badly idented, not sure if from copy/paste. Give it a try, if the commands need to be inserted in new lines finish them with "\n".

Comment: `-` before EOF is a Bash feature to trim leading tab indents.

Comment: you're right my bad, even though adjusting EOF and the last ")" it kinda worked for me. I used a random command in my box